# python taking derivatives of polynomials

Tags: python, algorithm, derivative

I want to take the derivative of polynomials for the given variable in python but i cant figure out where to start. I have tried to write recursive functions but i dont understand how to parse polynomial one by one? Should i seperate the coefficients and then write recursive function or something else? 
This is how my code should execute:

```
print derivative(x*y, x).string()
# x*0+1*y
print derivative(2*x*x+3*x+5, x).string()
# 2*x*1+(2*1+0*x)*x+(3*1+0*x)+0
```

Comment: Is this part of an bigger library? `derivative()` has to return an object which implements a `string()`-method. And what are the names `x`and `y` in this statements referring to? - If input was a string you should probably start with splitting the expression at `+`and `-`es to get the monomials, split those at the `*`es to identify the coefficient and count the variable for the power it is raised to. Then apply the formula for the derivative an put all together again.

Comment: Are you required to use `x*x` instead of, say, `x^2`?

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the derivates in every possible case is extremely extended subject. You are better off using a specialized library. The standard one is [Sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html). By using it, you can get the derivatives as a formula, eg

```
diff(cos(x), x) # returns -sin(x)
```